# Specifying the creation of a sudo user in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I want my Docker image to have a non-root user that can perform root/sudo commands.

How do I specify that in my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out by myself:

```
RUN useradd -m <username>
RUN sudo usermod -a -G sudo <username>
RUN echo "<username>:<password>"|chpasswd
```